# where do i find the ejabberd config directory with 19.0.5

Tags: ejabberd

I have installed ejabberd 19.0.5. But I can not found the config directory in my installer directory. And I uninstalled it. And install twice. But can not find too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When install ejabberd on linux machine you can specify the all ejabberd config dir into  one single dir using installtion command

Example:

**./configure --prefix=/opt/ejabberd**

So all the ejabberd related dir (bin,  etc,  lib,  sbin,  share, var) inside the /opt/ejabberd dir

Comment: Thank you,I will install ejabberd 19.05 in the centos7.6 server these days,what you said will help me,Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Optional parameters when starting an ejabberd node:
  --config-dir dir   Config ejabberd:    C:/ProgramData/ejabberd/conf
  --config file      Config ejabberd:    C:/ProgramData/ejabberd/conf/ejabberd.yml
  --ctl-config file  Config ejabberdctl: C:/ProgramData/ejabberd/conf/ejabberdctl.cfg
  --logs dir         Directory for logs: C:/ProgramData/ejabberd/logs
  --spool dir        Database spool dir: C:/ProgramData/ejabberd/database/ejabberd@localhost
  --node nodename    ejabberd node name: ejabberd@localhost

the ejabberdctl.cmd tell me,which in the bin directory,use windows powershell to run it